# Inserting documents in MongoDB in specific order using pymongo

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I have to insert documents in MongoDB in a left-shift manner i.e if the collection contains 60 documents, I am removing the 1st document and I want to insert the new document at the rear of the database. But when I am inserting the 61st element and so forth, the documents are being inserted in random positions.
Is there any way I can insert the documents in the order that I specified above?
Or do I have to do this processing when I am retrieving the values from the database? If yes then how?
The data format is :

```
data = {"time":"10:14:23", #timestamp 
         "stats":[<list of dictionaries>]
       }
```

The code I am using is

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient().test
db.timestamp.delete_one({"_id":db.timestamp.find()[0]["_id"]})
db.timestamp.insert_one(new_data)
```

the timestamp is the name of the collection.

Edit: Changed the code. Is there any better way?

```
from pymongo.operations import InsertOne,DeleteOne

def save(collection,data,cap=60):
    if collection.count() == cap:
        top_doc_time= min(doc['time'] for doc in collection.find())
        collection.delete_one({'time':top_doc_time['_time']})
    collection.insert_one(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bulk write operation [guarantees query ordering by default](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/).
This means that the queries are executed sequentially.

```
from pymongo.operations import DeleteOne, InsertOne


def left_shift_insert(collection, doc, cap=60):
    ops = []
    variance = max((collection.count() + 1) - cap, 0)
    delete_ops = [DeleteOne({})] * variance
    ops.extend(delete_ops)
    ops.append(InsertOne(doc))

    return collection.bulk_write(ops)

left_shift_insert(db.timestamp, new_data)
```

Comment: This solution is not working as I wanted it to be. Can you give me an alternative solution ?

Comment: probably this will also not work because after deletion insertion is performed in a random manner.

Comment: The mongo docs I linked to in my answer states that operations are ordered by default. I tried this out with a cap of 6 records and got the right results. Are you able to provide a sample I can work with?